# How to split a numpy array into batches where the number of rows in each batch is user specified

Tags: python, numpy, batch-processing

Say for example, I have a numpy array with 110 rows.

How do I split this array so that each split/batch has 20 rows, where the 20 is specified by the user? This will also need to take into account the last split/batch which has only 10 rows.

I know there are numpy functions like `np.array_split()` but this function does not let you specify how many rows each split/batch should have (it only lets you specify how many splits/batches that you want).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Split into list of sub-arrays with `[a[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(a), n)]` - or corresponding generator expression if you just want to loop over them, or just a for loop... but the bottom line is that ordinary slicing should be able to do this for you.

Comment: Many thanks, this works! Can I ask what does z mean in range(x, y, z)? I am used to only seeing x and y, but there is a 3rd element?

Comment: The third argument is the step (defaults to 1).

Comment: There is online documentation - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range - but also if you typed `help(range)` it would tell you this.

Comment: Yeah, I know. In my example above n=20, so it would be `range(0, 110, 20)`. What does is the 3rd argument in `range()` do?

Comment: Oh ok got you. The 3rd argument is the step size which is what I am after for the user specified value. Many thanks once again!